# qVariantValue is "QT_DEPRECATED" - what is the replacement?

Tags: c++, qt, qvariant

i need to convert Qt legacy code from 4 to 5.1 
now i have compilation error in visual studio 2010 :

```
SingleItem* item = qVariantValue<SingleItem*>(index.data());
```

gives me :

> .cpp(63): error C2065: 'qVariantValue' : undeclared identifier

when i go to the header i see :

```
#if QT_DEPRECATED_SINCE(5, 0)
template<typename T>
inline QT_DEPRECATED T qVariantValue(const QVariant &variant)
{ return qvariant_cast<T>(variant); }

template<typename T>
inline QT_DEPRECATED bool qVariantCanConvert(const QVariant &variant)
{ return variant.template canConvert<T>(); }
#endif
```

ok ... so what is the replacement?

Comment: I can't find `qVariantValue` with Google??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See the [compatibility notes](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qvariant-compat.html).

For `qVariantValue`, use `QVariant::value<T>` instead.

```
index.data().value<SingleItem*>();
```